# How to avoid \n inside a String while subclassing Log4j ConsoleAppender

Tags: java, log4j, appender

I have written a Log4j Custom Appender based on log4j's `ConsoleAppender`.

I am constructing a String based on the exception stacktrace i get , the problem i am facing is that i am seeing charcters '\n' inside it

Please see the below String i got which has characters like **\n** .

```
(Test.java:<sendSymbol>:40)- THE ERROR IS \norg.springframework.remoting.RemoteLookupFailureException: Lookup of RMI stub failed; nested exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 19.9.199.155; nested exception is: \n
```

This is my `CustomAppender` class

please let me know why i am getting `\n inside my String` .

```
package com;

import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.Layout;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation;

public class TestAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {
    public TestAppender() {



    }
    public TestAppender(Layout layout) {
        this.layout = layout;
    }
    public void append(LoggingEvent event) {

        ThrowableInformation throwableInfo = null;
        Throwable throwable = null;
        Throwable cause = null;
        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = null;
        String smallIndent = "";
        String largeIndent = " at ";
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        stringBuffer.append(this.layout.format(event));
        if ((throwableInfo = event.getThrowableInformation()) != null) {
            if ((throwable = throwableInfo.getThrowable()) != null) {
                cause = throwable;
                while (cause != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(smallIndent);
                    if (cause != throwable) {
                        stringBuffer.append("Caused by: ");
                    }
                    stringBuffer.append(cause.toString());
                    stackTrace = cause.getStackTrace();
                    for (int i = 0; i < stackTrace.length; i++) {
                        stringBuffer.append(largeIndent + stackTrace[i]);
                    }

                    cause = cause.getCause();
                }
            }
        }


        System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());

    }

    public boolean requiresLayout() {
        return true;
    }

    public void close() {
        if (this.closed) {
            return;
        }
        this.closed = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly doubt the newlines originate from anywhere else but the `stringBuffer.append(this.layout.format(event));` call. The other four calls should not add any new lines. From your output example :

```
stringBuffer.append(largeIndent + stackTrace[i]); // -- is never called
stringBuffer.append(smallIndent); // -- won't add newline
stringBuffer.append("Caused by: "); // -- won't add newline (and not called)
stringBuffer.append(cause.toString()); // -- shouldn't add newline
```

By "shouldn't" I mean, any Throwable subclass can override the toString() method in order to append a \n at the end, but they generally don't and `org.springframework.remoting.RemoteLookupFailureException` does not.

What Layout implementation does your class get initialized with? And how is that layout's `format()` method implemented? Hopefully your IDE supports conditional breakpoints and you can stop the debugger after an append if `stringBuffer.toString().contains("\n");`